# Invalid XML sign response with java signature method

Tags: java, xml

I have this java code with which I can sign an XML file with a .p12 certificate.

The requirements for this signature are the signatureMethod and the digetsMethod need to use sha256 as the encryption algorithm.

The DigestValue should be the Property that contains the value encoded in Base 64 format of the summary of the object described by the Uri property in the reference tag.

In this case, what changes should we make in order to meet all of this requirements. Also the requirement needs that the xml does not preserve white spaces.

Currently I am getting invalid signature when I test the signed XML.

Here is my code bellow so far:

```
package xmlCreateSignature;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.crypto.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dom.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.C14NMethodParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.TransformParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class testesas { 
  public static  void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      
 System.setProperty("com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.ignoreLineBreaks", "true");
 String pass ="pass" ;
 // Load the XML document
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance( );
  
 dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
// dbf.setNamespaceAware(false);
 dbf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
 DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

 org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(new File("./documents/request.xml"));
 doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

 // Load the certificate and private key from the .p12 file
 String providerName="SunJSSE";
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", providerName);
 ks.load(new FileInputStream("./documents/4300648_identity.p12"), pass.toCharArray());
 String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
 PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pass.toCharArray());
 Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);

 // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to generate the signature
 XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

  // Create a Reference to the whole document, using SHA256 digest algorithm
  Reference ref = fac.newReference("", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null),
 Collections.singletonList(
         fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)), null, null);

 // Create a SignedInfo with the above Reference
 SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo( 
 fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,
(C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA256 , null),
Collections.singletonList(ref));

 // Create a KeyInfo with the certificate information
 KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();

 X509Data x509d = kif.newX509Data(Collections.singletonList(cert));
 KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(x509d));

 // Create a new XML signature and sign the document with the private key
 DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, doc.getDocumentElement());
 XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);
 
 signature.sign(dsc);

 // Save the signed document to a file
 TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();

 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("./documents/response.xml"));
 

 trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), result);
 System.out.println("XML document signed successfully.");
  
  } 
}
```

**Bellow code is a fully functional C# code that is  generating valid signatures but for this case I need this to be generated on java**

```
//this is the class that generates the XML signed
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
     class xmlSign
    {


      

        public XmlDocument SignXmlWithP12(XmlDocument? xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            //Obtenemos la llave privada del certificado
            var llavePrivada = cert.PrivateKey;
            //Creamos un SignedXml object que contendrá el documento.
            SignedXml xmlFirmado = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
            //Atachamos la llave privada al SignedXml document.
            xmlFirmado.SigningKey = llavePrivada;
            //Creamos una referencia del documento a ser firmado.
            Reference reference = new Reference(); 
            reference.Uri   = ""; //Todo el documento
                  //Agregamos un enveloped transformation a la referencia.
            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new
            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform(true);
            reference.AddTransform(env);
            //Agregamos la referencia al SignedXml object.
            xmlFirmado.AddReference(reference);
            //Creamos un KeyInfo object.
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            //Cargamos el certificado dentro de un KeyInfoX509Data object
            //y luego lo añadimos al KeyInfo object.
            KeyInfoX509Data clause = new KeyInfoX509Data();
            //Opcionalmente se podría agregar el Subject del certificado
            //clause.AddSubjectName(cert.Subject);
            clause.AddCertificate(cert);
            keyInfo.AddClause(clause);
            //Asignamos el KeyInfo object al SignedXml object.
            xmlFirmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo; //Procedemos a
            //computar la firma.
                xmlFirmado.ComputeSignature();
            //Obtenemos la representación del XML firmado y la guardamos en un
          //  XmlElement object
            XmlElement xmlFirmaDigital = xmlFirmado.GetXml();
            //Adicionamos el elemento de la firma al documento XML.
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlFirmaDigital, true));
            
            return xmlDoc;
        }






      


    }
}

 


// this is the main class


using ConsoleApp2;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Xml;

xmlSign xmlsignedDOC= new xmlSign();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(  );

doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
doc.Load("C:\\Users\\FelixRojas\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApp2\\ConsoleApp2\\docs\\request.xml");



X509Certificate2 cert =

    new X509Certificate2(


        fileName: "C:\\Users\\FelixRojas\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApp2\\ConsoleApp2\\docs\\4300648_identity.p12",
        password:

        "pass"

        );
   

doc = xmlsignedDOC.SignXmlWithP12(doc, cert) ;


doc.Save("C:\\Users\\FelixRojas\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApp2\\ConsoleApp2\\docs\\request.xml");
```

I am able to generate the signed xml, but the digestValue and the SignatureValue are different that what are expected to be, and this results in invalid signature when I test it.

Comment: `replaceAll("\r\n", "");` has a limited scope - basically Windows line separators that are 'error free'. `replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");` would be better

Comment: Changing any character after signing may break the signature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it but  it still throws invalid signature  when i try to to validate the file.

Comment: thanks @aled i deleted all the  changes after signing but still  invalid

Comment: You haven't told us *how* you're testing the signature

Comment: I have to send the  signed XML to the server of the entity  that  gave me the  certificate but i want to know if  my  code meet all of the criteria that  the entity told me that they need for this  to be valid   because  I'm a c# developer and  i did it on c# and worked perfectly   but in java  with the same XML  I'm generating different SignatureValue and DigestValue.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to post the C#. There are many things that could break it - right from the start, e.g. the encoding with which it's read

Comment: That doesn't help me but might help someone else ;)

Comment: It's okey thanks for your help @g00se

Comment: Have you inspected in detail the differences in the C# and Java output?

Comment: The only difference in the output file generated is the SignatureValue and DigestValue.